# Nifi : Execute script Error (cannot create pystring with non-byte value)

Tags: python, apache-nifi, pyc, execute-script

I am trying to parse the flow file using executeScript processor. Basically, what I am doing is splitting the flowfile contents using python script and make a csv out of it. It ran fine for my sample data. But every prod message is about 10000 chars long.

In order to split this and convert the flow file to a csv, the python code became large. Running this got me error1. I tried converting this to pyc file and then I got error2.

Please let me know what can I do to resolve this.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Comment: How you got so large python code? Could you show it?

Comment: @daggett its mainly splitting the flowfile (10000 chars) into different fields (1800 fields). So this alone added 1800 lines to it.

Comment: Try to use executestreamcommant.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy scripts on Nifi I normally use this project:
https://github.com/mattyb149/nifi-script-tester

You can place python files in the resource for example: https://github.com/mattyb149/nifi-script-tester/blob/master/src/test/resources/test_json2json.py

and the test it.